# Can I use a concatenated var+array_value as a selector in jquery i.e $("#var+array_value")

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, var

This might be really obvious, but I'll be honest, I'm not any kind of developer.  Just someone trying to get something to work for customers of the company I work for.

I've got an array defined in JS, and I'd like to be able to use a for loop to run a section of code on each of the items in the array.

If I run the code individually (i.e. not in the loop), I know it works.  As soon as try to put it in a loop, it fails.  I'm hoping somebody here can tell me what I'm doing wrong, and why it is wrong, and how I can do it right.  (I'd like to be able to understand what/why I'm doing things, as its always better to know these things, in my opinion).

The JS/JQuery code I've got (that works) is;

```
var a = document.getElementById('roomthumb_2236');
var d = $("#chosenrate_2236").offset();

if ($('#chosenrate_2236').length) {
    a.style.visibility='visible';

    $("#roomthumb_2236").css({
        top: d.top -9 + "px",
        left: d.left + 560 + "px",
    })
};
```

This works fine (I know there is a mashup of JS and JQuery, I can standardise it later).

I've tried so many variations of the 'for' loop, but it just doesn't seem to want to work. Here is the most up-to-date version of my 'for' code;

```
var rooms_array = [2236, 2235]

var reposition = function (){
    document.getElementById('hidden_stuff').style.display="none";

    for (var i = 0; i < rooms_array.length; i++) {
        var a = "roomthumb_"+rooms_array[i];
        var b = "chosenrate_"+rooms_array[i];
        var c = "chosenrate_"+rooms_array[i].offset()

        if ($(b).length) {
            $(a).css({
                visibility:"visible",
                top: c.top -9 + "px",
                left: c.left + 560 + "px",
            })
        };
    };
};
```

What the code should be doing (if its not clear) is;

- set the array (this is a dynamically created list of id's from a database)
- hide a div "hiddenstuff" (this works fine)
- then for each id from the array;

  - create a variable 'roomthumb_xxxx' (where xxxx is the id from the array) called a
  - create a variable 'chosenrate_xxxx' (where xxxx is the id from the array) called b
  - check to see if an element exists with an ID that matches variable b, and if it does then edit the css properties of the element with the ID of variable a

The var c should get the position of var b (if I'm right), to allow me to position the element with the ID of var a relative to it...

I've no idea why the code fails inside of the loop.  I always seem to get null errors or it thinks var b is undefined?

My guess is that I can't take a string (chosenrate_), add an array string to it and then use that result as an ID.  If I use alert(a) or alert(b) I do get the ID's I need, but I can't work out how to use that in a $("#ID") for example...

I think I've explained everything.  If I've missed anything I'll try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something similar to this code will do the job for you:

```
// Your array with data.
var rooms_array = [2235, 2236, 2237, 2238];
var reposition = function (){
    // Hide whatever you need to hide.
    $('#hidden_stuff').attr('display', "none");
    // This is a jQuery function to iterate over arrays.
    $.each(rooms_array, function(key,value){
        // Create your "a" variable
        var a = '#roomthumb_'+value;  // roomthumb_2235  ; roomthumb_2236 ...
        var b = '#chosenrate_'+value; // chosenrate_2235 ; chosenrate_2236 ...

        // If b exists...
        if ($(b).length) {
            var c = $(b).offset(); // get the offset of "b"
            $(a).css({
                visibility:"visible",
                top: c.top -9 + "px",
                left: c.left + 560 + "px"
            })
        }
        // if "b" doesn't exist
        else {
            // edit the css properties of the element with the ID of variable "a"
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This code works better than the code I had (I was getting one warning in Chrome's 'console'), which is now gone.  I think its probably down to only trying to et the .offset if b exists, which I wasn't doing before.

Overall, I'd say this is the most complete, and successful answer.
I'd upvote, only I don't have enough rep yet...

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Don't worry 'bout the upvote. Cheers! :)

Comment: Can you look at my other issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385211/jquery-fancybox-plugin-using-arrays-in-code)??

The idea of using classes someone suggested doesn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
var a = "#roomthumb_"+rooms_array[i]; // put # sign for id selector
var b = "#chosenrate_"+rooms_array[i];
var c = $("#chosenrate_"+rooms_array[i]).offset();
```

you can also write `var c` as:

```
var c = $(b).offset(); // where var b = "#chosenrate_"+rooms_array[i];
```

instead of what you're currently trying.

As you're trying to point to `id` so you need `#` at begin.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks.  Also thanks to greg and vins for their answers.  Tried this first, so would have to take it as the answer.

Comment: I do have another issue, which you may be able to help with..

I've got another section of code, which I was running in a separate for loop, but I assume I could run it in this one.  I've asked it as another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385211/jquery-fancybox-plugin-using-arrays-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can concatenate strings to make jQuery selectors. After a quick look I can see that the problem is probably the value of `c`. Also, you're missing the hashes from the beginnings of the selectors. Replace this:

`var c = $("chosenrate_" + rooms_array[i]).offset()`

with:

```
var a = "#roomthumb_" + rooms_array[i];
var b = "#chosenrate_" + rooms_array[i];
var c = $("#chosenrate_" + rooms_array[i]).offset()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a wrong thing in writing your selector.
As per your question `$(“#var+array_value”)` This should be `$(“#"+var+array_value)`